# High TPS (3k -4k) API in Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule-component

1. Does Mulesoft support such high TPS APIs(3k -4k) ?
2. If it supports and if someone has done it in past can you please provide some pointers w.r.t below metrics?
   a) vcores
   b) memory usage
   c)N/W bandwidth

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that without more context this question is meaningless. 4000 TPS doing what exactly? For what is worth there is a performance whitepaper in MuleSoft website with some of the data you are searching for (TPS, vCores, CPU): https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/reports/mule4-runtime-engine-performance. It is for the described use cases which may or not match your use case. I'm not sure what do you need network bandwidth for.